# synaptic update installed packages

Tags: ubuntu, offline

i used synaptic in order to download all the dependencies of modules i need in

order to install them in an offline computer.

the problem is that the packeges that synaptic download are not the latest vesions..

for example: i downloaded Django framework with synpatic - but the only version of djnago available in synaptic is 1.6.1.. (now there is a 1.9 version..)

i tried to find a solution online but the answer i got to is that it can not be done..

any idea how can i get the latest versions so i can move them to an offline computer?

Comment: Ubuntu manages which versions of packages are available to each release. Sometimes you have better luck adding the 'backports' channel into your sources for synaptic.

Comment: sorry, but i didn't understand what you mean..

Comment: See these answers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25717/how-do-i-enable-the-backports-repository

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your repository and install the latest version of the synaptic with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synaptic
synaptic
```